# grep logfile for a specific timeframe

Tags: python, bash, awk, grep

I need to filter messages out of a log file which has the following format:

```
2013-03-22T11:43:21.817078+01:00  INFO    log msg 1...
...
2013-03-22T11:44:32.817114+01:00  WARNING log msg 2...
...
2013-03-22T11:45:45.817777+01:00  INFO    log msg 3...
...
2013-03-22T11:46:59.547325+01:00  INFO    log msg 4...
...
```

(where `...` means "more messages")

The filtering must be done based on a timeframe.
This is part of a bash script, and at this point in the code the timeframe is stored as `$start_time` and `$end_time`. For example:

```
start_time = "2013-03-22T11:45:20"
end_time   = "2013-03-22T11:45:50"
```

Note that the ***exact*** value of `$start_time` or `$end_time may` may never appear in the log file; yet there will be several messages *within the timeframe* `[$start_time, $end_time]` which are the ones I'm looking for.

Now, I'm almost convinced I'll need a Python script to do the filtering, but I'd rather use grep (or awk, or any other tool) since it should run much faster (the log files are big).

Any suggestions?

Comment: if your `start_time` is shell variable, remove those spaces before and after `=` when you assign value to it. (the same for `end_time`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the log content in your question, I think an awk oneliner may help:

```
awk -F'.' -vs="$start_time" -ve="$end_time" '$1>s && $1<e' logfile
```

Note: this is filtering content excluding the start and end time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ start_time="2013-03-22T11:45:20"

$ end_time="2013-03-22T11:45:50"

$ awk -F'.' '$1>s&&$1<e' s=$start_time e=$end_time file
2013-03-22T11:45:45.817777+01:00  INFO    log msg 3...
```